# spin image clockwise/anticlockwise on touch

Tags: iphone

Any idea about how to spin image clockwise/anticlockwise on touch.

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more information. Have you got some code which isn't working or are you looking for ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 4):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> 

[UIView beginAnimations:@"RotationAnimation" context:nil];

CABasicAnimation *fullRotationAnimation;
fullRotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotationAnimation .fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotationAnimation.duration = 2;          // speed for the rotation. Smaller number is faster
fullRotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1e100f;  // number of times to spin. 1 = once
[myImage.layer addAnimation:fullRotationAnimation forKey:@"360"];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Actually, I don't believe the begin / commit animations block for the UIView is necessary here, because you are explicitly animating the view's layer.  You may also want to use "transform.rotation.z" as the keypath for the animation, to clearly specify what axis is being rotated about.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use CoreAnimation for this; basically you'll need to apply an animation to the transform property of your image view. There are plenty of [samples](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) on Apple's developer page that show variations on this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the late answer to your question, but it will help someone..
By using the [CGAffineTransformMakeRotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) we can able to rotate the Image

**Rotate the Image in Anti-Clockwise Direction**

```
-(void)rotate
    {
        x++;
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(x);
        imageView.transform = transform;
        [self performSelector:@selector(rotate) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];

    }
```

**For ClockWise Direction** use x--;